# Why is the photo of the black hole not black where the actual body is?

Tags: optics, black-holes

Look at the photo here https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap190411.html

The centre of the black hole isn't that dark. For comparison, here is the same photo with a black overlay in the centre. Notice the difference. The original is not even close to be black.

[image]

Comment: See the diagram in https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/30360/16685

Comment: It could be because of the resolution of the image?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the resolution in the image,

Take a look at the bottom of [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/30360) answer for a comparison between a blurred simulation and the actual picture.